# Using teamcity artifacts in another project

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

Since TeamCity supports many languages, this question might be very tight coupled with the way, projects work in Visual Studio. So here is my question:

For instance, I have a project A in Visual Studio, and I want to add it to TeamCity in order to support continues integration. Now there is another project B. This project depends on project A. Now, how do I reference project A in project B? And how do I update it properly? I know that I can generate artifacts in project A, but I think I'm supposed to download them manually?

Comment: Before we get too far here -- have you tried putting projects a and b in the same visual studio solution and using that to handle the dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home) for that. Please take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/12/01/setting-up-teamcity-as-a-native-nuget-server/) for more details about TeamCity + NuGet integration.